# javascript generate array with only mulitiples of 5

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a use case where i need to create a array with only multiples of 5 and I need to achieve this in one line and do not want to use a for loop or any kind of loop.

My output should be like:

```
const arr = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]
```

i have tried the below method,

```
const arr = [...Array(10).keys()] // creates a array with values [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Let me know if there is anyway I can achieve the above result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mapping callback of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const theArray =
    Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 5);

console.log(theArray);
```

The first argument is any array-like, and the second (optional) argument is the mapping function. `{length: 10}` gives us an object with `length` set to 10 without allocating any array storage,¹ then `from` creates the actual array with the return values from the mapping callback. The mapping callback is called with each value (always `undefined` in this case) and the index of that value (0-based). `(index + 1) * 5` gives us increments of 5.

---

¹ In contrast, `Array(10)` may allocate array storage even though it doesn't end up getting used. This varies by JavaScript engine, but for instance V8 (in Chromium-based browsers) actually allocates array storage for `Array(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in many ways, I used `map()`. Since the `index` is starting from `0`, You should add `1` then multiply it with `5`.

```js
const arr = [...Array(10).keys()].map(i => (i + 1) * 5 );

console.log(arr);
```